# How can helm be configured to return a nil result when the user cancels?

Tags: helm, completion

This function selects one of the items in projectile's project list, but when I cancel the select using `Ctrl-G` an item is still returned. Whatever candidate the selection is on is returned even if the dialog is cancelled.

Is there some setting to override this behaviour?

```
  (defun vh-select-project()
    (interactive)
    (let ( (projectlist
                 (with-temp-buffer
                   (save-excursion
                     ;;(insert "(progn\n")
                     (insert-file-contents-literally (expand-file-name "projectile-bookmarks.eld" user-emacs-directory))
                     (goto-char (point-max))
                     ;;(insert "\n)")
                     (read (buffer-string)))))

           (input (progn
                    (helm :sources
                          (list (helm-build-sync-source "Select project:"
                                  :candidates projectlist)))
                    (helm-marked-candidates)
                    )))
      (when project
        (insert (car project) ""))
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the action slot (see the last line):

```lisp
(helm :sources (helm-build-sync-source "Select project:"
                 :candidates projectile-known-projects
                 :action 'insert))
```